# JavaScript Sorting a Function That Has multiple Numbers

Tags: sorting

I am trying to create a Random Lottery Number Generator code but I am having issues sorting the numbers from lower to greater. Here is my code of getting the numbers but I can't seem to figure out how to sort them.

```
function ball(){
  let ball = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 70);
  console.log(ball);
}

function whiteBalls(){
  for(let i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
    ball();
  }
}

whiteBalls();
```

I've tried many different ways but keep getting errors. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) and then [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) it. Then, loop through and print it afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the result in an array and sort the array:

```
function ball() {
    return Math.ceil(Math.random() * 70);
}

function whiteBalls() {
    let result = []
    for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        result.push(ball());
    }
    return result.sort()
}
 
console.log(whiteBalls());
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response/answer!!!!